# Entity - Map types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-6

I have an entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public DateTime Time{get;set;}
}
```

Now, one of our db guidelines tells is we should store a date as an int to save some space.

I've currently fixed it like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Column("Time")]
    public int TimeAsInt
    {
        get { return Time.AsInt(); }//Extension methods on int/datetime
        set { Time = value.AsDateTime(); }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to mess up my POCO objects? I was hoping that I wouldn't have to change my model to use Entity, just add some extra entity mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to be stuck adding that field but I would suggest you change your Poco to something like this, so you only have to do the cast when you need it.

```
public class MyEntity
{
   [NotMapped]
   public DateTime Time { 
     get{
      return Time.AsInt()  
     }

     set{
      TimeAsInt = value.AsInt();
     }

    [Column("Time")]
    public int TimeAsInt{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: In our code we'll be using the datetime most of the time and only use the timeasint to go to the db. So it makes more sense to me to do the mapping in the timeasint.